# babel.config.js is still running from cache after reload the app

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, babeljs, babel-loader

In my expo-ejected react native project,
with the intention of completely disabling a preset, i commented it from babel.config.js like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache.never();
  return {
    // presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

Notice that i also added

```
api.cache.never();
```

So I expect it won't hit the cache and run everytime i build.

My purpose of disabling it is to avoid some module resolution that this preset does.
It basically changes module names from **react-native-vector-icons** to **@expo/vector-icons**

But it is still applying and changing this module names.

I also try **yarn cache clean** with no success.

Comment: FYI `api.cache.never();` here doesn't do anything that matters in this context. Maybe something else is injecting additional Babel configuration?

Comment: Yes, it seems so, thanks. But i don't know what else can inject additional conf. Do you know that can anything in node_modules run their own babel conf? Is it something possible?